# Java Method that returns a String containing that number of adjacent dots

Tags: java, algorithm

The method should return an empty string if count is less then 1.  I have started, but can't finish the last part where you have to add the number of dots.

My code:

```
public String numOfDots (int count) {
    if(count < 1) 
        return " ";

    int numOfDots = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; )
```

What do I need to do from here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286304/method-that-returns-a-string-containing-that-number-of-adjacent-stars

Comment: First, `" "` isn't the empty string `""`.  Second, how do you iterate through each character of the String and determine if it's a dot?

Comment: What is the expected input and expected output of this function?

Comment: Would you know how to add a dot to an existing string?

Comment: For example numOfDots(4) prints output; ••••

Comment: Just need to know the source code that will print the number of dots. Anyone?

Comment: @rohulla mohammadi Strings support concatenation, e.g. `"." + "." is a new string, ".."` You can also add onto a string by doing `s += "."`. I suggest you read a good online tutorial on Java

Comment: how about doing your homework yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public String numOfDots(int count)
{
    StringBuilder retrStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (; count > 0; count--)
        retrStr.append("*");
    return retrStr.toString();
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: No problem, but do try to do some research before posting here. StringBuilder is not the most complex thing to find.

Answer (score 0):

In Clojure (hey, the question is just tagged algorithm):

```
(defn numOfDots [count]
  (clojure.string/join "" (repeat count "."))
)
```

Output ([try it yourself](http://tryclj.com/)):

```
(numOfDots 10)
..........
```